# Handling a conditional statement in a single line

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Is it possible to write following **C# code** *in a line* without `if` and `else`?

```cs
string res = "";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1))
    res = string.Format("{0}/{1}", var1, var2);
else
    res = var2;
```

Comment: res = condition ? resultiftrue : resultiffalse

Comment: you're looking for the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Why do you need the code written in one line only?

Comment: You can quickly find that by googling terms like those in the title of your question, (along with 'C#', even if the same operator exists in many languages anyway) https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: string res = string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1) ? var2 : string.Format("{0}/{1}", var1, var2) ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
string res = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1) ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", var1, var2) : var2;
```

Basically,
`(if this statement is true (like if block's condition part)) ? (this section works) : ((else) this section works);`

Hope this helps,

Comment: As OP does not know what the ternary operator is, perhaps it would be prudent to include an explanation in this answer?

Comment: You are right, tried to explain basically. @Martin

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator ?:, also known as the ternary conditional operator, evaluates a Boolean expression and returns the result of one of the two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression evaluates to true or false. 
The syntax for the conditional operator is as follows:

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

So the code line you are requested is

```
string res = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1) ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", var1, var2) : var2;
```

Comment: As OP clearly does not know what the ternary operator is, perhaps it would be prudent to include an explanation in this answer?

Comment: Added explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tecnically, you can hide `if` within *ternary operator* `?:`

```
  string res = $"{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1) ? $"{var1}/" : "")}{var2}";
```

but *what for*?